# If $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f\ll1$ then $\int_{|z|=1}f\ll4$

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality, complex-integration

Show that if $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and $f\ll1$ ($a\ll b$ means $|a|\leq |b|$), then $\int_{|z|=1}f\ll4$.

Hint: Show first $\int f\ll\int_0^{2\pi} |\sin t|dt$.

I'm not sure how to prove the hint. In addition, what does the notation of $|z|=1$ below the $\int$ sign means?

Comment: The $\int_{|z|=1}$ is a contour integral on the contour $|z|=1$, i e. a circle centered at $0$ with radius $1$.

Comment: Please write the intended integral correctly. It is unclear what the assumed $d\ldots$ is. With the line element $ds$ the claim seems wrong.